# Eclipse unfocussed behaviour

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-18.04

I am running eclipse `Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)`
When i take focus off the main window, such as a Find/Replace (or other running program) the main window becomes dim, as seen below. This only started after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.10. Prior to this I was having normal visibility in both windows.

This makes it difficult to see what has been found in the Find/Replace window.

Is there a setting in eclipse that can be set for this ?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate and identical contents https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112264/how-can-a-theme-or-preference-avoid-graying-out-a-background-window-when-a-non-m

Comment: Yes, this is a Duplicate. Keeping for visibility.

Comment: This is now no longer a problem with Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0) & ubuntu 19.10.